# SSL certificate authentication on Outlook 365 (cloud)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, ssl, office365, ssl-certificate

We can send emails using an Office 365 account from third-party devices using STARTTLS encryption on a SMTP server (port 587).

The device I am using does not support STARTTLS, only plain vanilla SMTP (port 25) or an SSL certificate type connection. How can I activate SSL certificates for my Office 365 account?

[This page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365) outlines three alternatives to use in such a situation, however :

- Option 1: My device is not compatible
- Option 2: I need to send to users outside of my domain
- Option 3: I don't know the IP addresses of my devices (there are many), and even if I did the addresses are susceptible to change. Also requires setting up a 3rd party server/service which is not desirable.

In outlook (the desktop app) it is possible to authenticate with an SMTP server by installing an SSL certificate. How can I render the Outlook 365 server compatible with SSL authentication?

Comment: Client cert authentication can be used also with STARTTLS. It just have to be supported by the client. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26919123/150978

Answer (score 1):

"TLS" is just the name for the newer version of "SSL". [Reference](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/tls-vs-ssl/).

<s>[Office 365 supports TLS and STARTTLS on port 587](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365).</s> Their website says "TLS/StartTLS", however, only STARTTLS is support as mentioned by @Robert in the comments.

With the program/service/device that only has SSL and insecure SMTP: try using SSL with port 587. If you cannot sent e-mails, that means the software does not support the minimum SSL/TLS version that Office 365 requires. There's no way to fix this unless the software has a newer version with TLS/STARTTLS support that you can upgrade to.

Not a recommendation, but a workaround: In Outlook, you might be able to install the certificate into Certificate Manager. When you see the certificate prompt, open it up and Export it as a P7B or PFX (preferred) file. Then go to Start->Search for "certmgr.msc". Go into Personal->Certificates, right-click and Import the certificate you exported. Restart Outlook. Not a guarantee to work, but has worked for me in the past in one-off situations.

If all else fails, I recommend setting up an intermediary/relay SMTP server on the network to handle this. *I know you specifically mentioned this is not desired, but mentioning it here as a possible solution if you can't get anything else to work.* E-mails will flow into the relay, then it will forward those through the Office 365 SMTP address using TLS/STARTTLS on port 587. **Make sure to lock it down - restrict access by IP address and enforce other security recommendations, otherwise outside users could use it for spam/phishing.**

If you have a Windows Server, [the SMTP role is on all editions](https://support.hostway.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002248059-How-to-Set-Up-An-Internal-SMTP-Service-For-Windows-Server).
With Linux [you have many options](https://www.gmass.co/blog/smtp-server-linux/) as well.

Comment: Also, don't confuse this with client certificate authentication.  Client Certificate Authentication is a replacement/addition to a password authentication used in Outlook. What we're talking about is the connection to Office 365's SMTP server using a secure connection.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is wrong. smtp.office365.com:587 does not support TLS, only STARTTLS is supported: `openssl s_client -connect smtp.office365.com:587` -> error  `openssl s_client -connect smtp.office365.com:587 -starttls smtp` -> works.

Comment: [According to their website](https://i.imgur.com/TxKsAHL.png), which is linked in my answer, it says "TLS/StartTLS" so the assumption is that it is supported, unless they mean "TLS via STARTTLS". You are correct, upon checking it does not appear that TLS is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is an Office 365 SSL encrypt issue. Tried some research and found that this article [Plan for third-party SSL certificates for Microsoft 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/plan-for-third-party-ssl-certificates?view=o365-worldwide) describes that to encrypt communications between your clients and the Microsoft 365 environment, third-party Secure Socket Layer (SSL) certificates must be installed on your infrastructure servers.

By the way, have you ever tried to post your issue to the [Dedicated Office365 Forum](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365/bd-p/Office365General)? Maybe the support there got more specific information about that?